# Firefox 32.0.2 transform issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

I found problem in new Firefox 32.0.2
http://jsfiddle.net/hdxoo9wy/1/
Here is example.

HTML

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="ob3d"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html,body{
     height: 100%;
}
.box{
    perspective: 1000px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: 10%;
    border: 1px rgba(0,255,0,0.2) dashed;
}
.ob3d{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform: rotateX(0.5deg);
    background: rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
    transform-origin: 50% 100% 0;
    outline: 1px transparent solid;
    animation: bounce 5s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes bounce{
  0%   { transform: rotateX(-20deg);}
  50% { transform: rotateX(20deg);}
  100% { transform: rotateX(-20deg);}
}
```

Problem appears during rotationX in range -0.5deg , 0.5deg . It jumps and gives a bit random effect. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1078262 here I reported bug. Will be fixed with FF 34